# Running Java Program Multiple Times on Mac

Tags: java, macos

Q. Is there a way to have a java program run twice on a mac like on windows?

Comment: Can't you launch two different processes from the same jvm in which case you should explore ProcessBuilder.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the Right way to structure an application on OS X. What you're supposed to do is have only one process for the "application" – the user interface. You can use "helper" processes to do some tasks in the background like downloading.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by run twice?  Do you want a second program to start once the first one has ended, or have two running simultaneously?  Specifically, what about Windows are you trying to recreate?

Comment: I want to have two instances of the same program run simultaneously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not specify if you want to start a simple .jar or an application-bundle so I will give examples for both. To run multiple instances of an application-bundle on OS X, you can use the following trick; open the Terminal and start the application with this command:

```
open -n /path/to/your/java.app
```

Each time you call this command, a new instance is opened up.

**Attention:** Just because it is possible to start several instances does not mean it is a good idea to do so. Make sure you will not run into trouble with concurrent write-access of multiple instances with the same file.

If you are trying to run a jar, you can simply call

```
java -jar /path/to/your/java.jar
```

several times to start up several instances.

To start up the java-application from inside a java-application under OSX, you have to do something like this:

In the case of a simple jar:

```
File jarFile = new File("/path/to/your/jarFile.jar");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "java", "-jar", jarFile.getAbsolutePath() });
```

In the case of an application bundle:

```
File jarFile = new File("/path/to/your/jarFile.app");
final String[] command = { "open", "-n", jarFile.getAbsolutePath() };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem. But why don't you abstract it to a method instead of naming it program and call that subroutine twice. Or spawn two threads?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a trick question, but I would open up two terminal windows and run it once on each terminal...

Comment: It works that way but for some reason when you call the program from within the program it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the nature of your Java program. If your program is running as both server and client, it may cause the problem when your run multiple instances. In many server program, it uses a fixed port number to simplify the setting and implementation. Since a given port number cannot be use by more than one application, you cannot open more than one instance of that application unless you can change the port number in your application settings.

Many Java application uses this trick to prevent user to open multiple instances of their program by checking if a certain port is in use. If this the case, then you cannot run more than one instance of the program.

For other Java application that do not use port or ports do not crash, you can open it twice or more via the terminal.

Comment: In my program the user enters the desired port number

Comment: Can you not run it twice then? what is the problem?

Comment: on mac when you double click on an application icon it either runs the program but if it already running it just takes you to it window >.<

Comment: Make a copy of your java program and run the second one from the copy. Does this help?

Comment: What is the version of your Java? Is it Sun? I don't know about how Java instance work on MacOSX but if it doesn't work then it's the problem with the Java on OSX becuase on other OSs there is no such a problem. Also try running it from two terminals to see if you can run it twice? It is possible that the double click behaves differently from running from terminal. The OS may remember the process when you execute it by double click on it.

Comment: If you run it from two terminal windows it works but if you try to run the program again from within the program nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running client version of the code on your system and trying to connect to a host. First you need to have the server running on both the machines, B and C in your case.  Secondly the client code you are using should be reading the IP address and port to connect.  It should not be hard coded or else you will have to change the code and rebuild it for server B.  This should help you.

Guess I have answered your query.
:)